# Increasing limit SweetHome3D

Tags: sweethome3d

I'm building a map of a large building in SweetHome3D.

The length of the building is 128 meters. When I try to import a background image for the building online, there's a limit of 100m. There's also a limit in the desktop application.

How can I increase that limit?

Answer (score 0):

By switching to meters, it's possible to enter measures longer than 100m. Somehow, the max units are not consistent. The limit is 100000m if you are working in meters and 100m if you are working in millimeters (100000mm = 100m).